# How do I follow links (or scrape multiple links) when web scraping with urllib2?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, urllib

I am attempting to scrape the url 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife&appid=730#p1' (for purely information purposes), but I cannot seem to figure out how to go to the next page. My current code is the following, but it just loops through the first page repeatedly instead of going to the next page.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_num = 1

while True:
    url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search? q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife&appid=730#p' + str(page_num)
    open_url = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    market_page = BeautifulSoup(read_url)

    for i in market_page('div', {'class' : 'market_listing_row      market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult'}):
        item_name = i.find_all('span', {'class' : 'market_listing_item_name'})[0].get_text()
        price = i.find_all('span')[1].get_text()
        page_num += 1
        print  item_name + ' costs ' + price
```

EDIT:
Also, the problem with the page I'm trying to scrape is that the links to the next page do not have any hrefs, so I was using a loop to try to go to different URLs, but it just scrapes the first URL repeatedly.

Comment: I think your spacing may be off in the code you posted... as is it'll just loop forever around that first url line

Comment: In addition to what lemonhead said, you're not including in the script when to end the loop. You're increasing it by 1 without a limit. Once it reaches page 90 from the url it will go to 91, but that page doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah lemonhead, I formatted the code in my question wrong. And Leb, shouldn't the code at least output the first 90 pages? It is just repeating the first page.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages  = 90

for page in range(pages):
    url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search? q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_Knife&appid=730#p' + str(page)
    open_url = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    market_page = BeautifulSoup(read_url)

    for i in market_page('div', {'class' : 'market_listing_row      market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult'}):
        item_name = i.find_all('span', {'class' : 'market_listing_item_name'})[0].get_text()
        price = i.find_all('span')[1].get_text()
        print  item_name + ' costs ' + price
```

Comment: You copied and pasted some code from the link you gave, which makes the code not work at all.

Comment: Also, the problem with the page I'm trying to scrape is that the links to the next page do not have any hrefs, so I was using a loop to try to go to different URLs, but it just scrapes the first URL repeatedly.

Comment: you page_num += 1 is on the for move it out

Comment: I think is better use the for 1 to 90 pages the  `while true` I maybe will fail to the end